# Android - how to migrate from LintOptions to Lint in a plugin of a multi-module app

Tags: android, android-lint, android-multi-module

I have a multi-module app which uses a plugin to handle common settings for modules. One of the things I configure are some lint options. So far this was my implementation:

```
class MyPlugin : Plugin<Project> {
    override fun apply(project: Project) {
        project.plugins.apply("kotlin-android")
        val androidExtension = project.extensions.getByName("android")
        if (androidExtension is BaseExtension) {
            androidExtension.apply {
                lintOptions {
                    isAbortOnError = false
                    //other settings
                }
            }
        }
}
```

I am getting warnings about deprecation such as:

> 'isAbortOnError: Boolean' is deprecated. Overrides deprecated member
> in 'com.android.build.api.dsl.LintOptions'. Moved to lint.abortOnError

I would like to move to Lint as suggested, but BaseExtension does not have lint, only lintOptions. How to do it?

Answer (score 3):

You can use this in

```
project.configure<com.android.build.api.dsl.ApplicationExtension> {
   lint {
        abortOnError = true
    }
}
```

I'm using it with `AGP 8.1.0-alpha10`, but it will be probably valid also in older AGP.

`BaseExtension` is now part of the internal API and just because of compatibility with older projects.

You should now depend only on
`com.android.tools.build:gradle-api`
artifact instead of
`com.android.tools.build:gradle`

At least in an ideal situation.